# Google Maps not loading routes with React + Flask

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, flask, iframe

### The problem

Hi all,

I'm new to both React and Flask so sorry if this is a simple problem, but basically, I have two inputs (starting/ending locations) that get passed to the Flask backend that goes through an algorithm and then exports the Google Map route as a *.html*; I can input the start/end locations and create the new route, it just doesn't update in real-time as I have to refresh the page to see the results.

In my *App.js* I have a simple iframe to embed the results as

```
<iframe id="Google-Map" src={"./map.html"} width="75%" height="500vh"></iframe>
```

How would I be able to allow it to refresh in real-time?

### What I’ve tried

I've tried the following

```
import Map from './map.html';

function App(){
...
<iframe id="Google-Map" src={"./map.html"} width="75%" height="500vh"></iframe>
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/map.html 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <html>
| <head>
| <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-30
 @ ./src/index.js 6:0-24 10:33-36

webpack 5.65.0 compiled with 1 error and 1 warning in 66 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your `html` file in a public place, not under the `src` folder. Because somehow the files under the `src` folder are not visible.

You can edit your `iframe` line like this:

```
<iframe id="Google-Map" src="../map.html" width="75%" height="500vh"></iframe>
```

Comment: I've been working at this for a little more, I think it's a little more in-depth with the POST/GET rather than the file location. Putting the *map.html* in the *public* folder definitely has helped though, thanks!